# How to implement Hadoop mapreduce job as non map/reduce even if does not make any sense?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Even if it does not make any sense for me to implement Hadoop Job in non map/reduce manner, I need to implement it for my project at University

How Hadoop Job can be run as non map/reduce? Is it enough just to set reducers to 0?

```
job.setNumreduceTasks(0)
```

or there is another way?

My application is working perfectly with mapper and reducer class, counting problem is solved (similar to world count, but in biological way).

Comment: Why not use Spark?

Comment: Another group is using Spark for the same task, so I am not sure will it be valid solution to run Spark on top of the Hadoop in my project? So I am looking for another possibilities.

Comment: Almost no one uses MapReduce these days. If you need to process data in a distributed manner on a Hadoop cluster, use Spark unless there's a very good reason to use something else. Spark is far more likely to be useful for you after graduation.

Comment: @Ben Although Hive, Pig, Sqoop, etc still use MapReduce? People use those

Comment: @cricket_007 yes but they're not writing MapReduce directly which was my point.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you created a Job class which requires you to set mapper and reducer classes, by definition, is making you do mapreduce.

If you must use Hadoop, and if you don't want to perform **multiple** map or reduce operation (e.g. not parallelize the operation), you would need to not split the file via the InputFormat (which by default reads line by line of file).

If you make the mapper only read one split, it'll process the entire file. You can either parse the entire file within the mapper task, you can pass it through directly to the reducer and do it there.

Basically, you're just causing the data to be reserialized at that point

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not use map/reduce operations and you want to run all code on driver you should implement [Tool](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) interface without creating any jobs:

```
public class MyApp extends Configured implements Tool {

   public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
     // your code
   }
}
```

But if you want to use only mappers you can just set `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`